# How to have an Image fill Height while growing in Width in a UMG Panel?

Tags: unreal-engine5

In a UMG Widget I have a HorizontalBox containing an Image to the left and another Panel with a buch of Widgets in it to the right.
I want that image to fill the full height of its parent while scaling the width so it keeps the same aspect ratio. The remaining with of the HorizontalBox should then be given to the panel on the right side.

However I can't get that to work. Either it streches the image to fill the height, or it shrinks to it's hardcoded base size to maintain the aspect ratio. Reading through the Slate Code of HorizontalBox seems to indicate that it is not capable of calculating child widths based on the available height. It just does a call to `GetDesiredSize()` and takes the appropriate component of that (in this case `x`).

So how can I achieve my desired Layout without doing some hacky calculations in `Tick` or `OnPaint`? (Preferably without creating my own Slate Panel)

To visualize what kind of Layout I'm looking for, here's an Example in HTML using flexbox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .image-container {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .image-container img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .text-container {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://img.uline.com/is/image/uline/H-8884?$Mobile_SI$" alt="Your Image">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam auctor ultricies nisi eget vestibulum.</h1>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```